# Detect when data has passed through a stream chain without finishing the chain

Tags: node.js, node.js-stream

I am piping a number of files through a cipher stream and then writing the result all to the same file. I can accomplish this by doing `src_file_1.pipe(cipher, {end: false}).pipe(dest_file, {end: false});`, `src_file_2.pipe(cipher, {end: false}).pipe(dest_file, {end: false});`, etc, but I am unable to close out the dest_file stream because it is impossible to know when cipher is done writing. If I do not specify `{end: false}` in the chain, then it is impossible to re-use cipher (reusing the same cipher is a requirement of my application).

Thus `src_file1.on('end', function()...)` is insufficient, since when this runs, data might still not have run through cipher, and `dest_file.on('finish, function()...)` is impossible to use since it will never fire unless I don't specify `{end: false}`.... So what I basically need is a way of telling if a chain of streams is done processing its current load, without ending anything in the chain.

Comment: update: if someone knows how to force a flush on the newer version of the streams API, that would work

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like the short answer is this simply cannot be done without severely hacking the Node.js streams API and subclassing a few things. Ever since flush() support was removed from the public API, the only way to use pipe in a chain and expect all the data to pass through is to end() the chain.

In my case, I was relying on some progress-stream streams that I wanted to keep open and reuse, but I ended up simply re-instantiating these using the last reported progress.transferred, progress.length, progress.percentage parameters. Similarly, I ended up having to re-instantiate my cipher each time, which turned out not to be a performance bottleneck since I was re-using the same key and iv for my particular application.